# Spring JUnit4 manual-/auto-wiring dilemma

Tags: java, spring, ioc-container, junit4, autowired

I ran into an issue that can only be explained with my fundamental lack of understanding of Spring's IoC container facilities and context setup, so I would ask for clarification regarding this.

Just for reference, an application I am maintaing has the following stack of technologies:

- Java 1.6
- Spring 2.5.6
- RichFaces 3.3.1-GA UI
- Spring framework is used for bean management with Spring JDBC module used for DAO support
- Maven is used as build manager
- JUnit 4.4 is now introduced as test engine

I am retroactively (sic!) writing JUnit tests for the application and what suprised me is that I wasn't able to inject a bean into a test class by using setter injection without resorting to @Autowire notation.

Let me provide set up an example and accompanying configuration files.

The test class `TypeTest` is really simple:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class TypeTest {

    @Autowired
    private IType type;

    @Test
    public void testFindAllTypes() {
        List<Type> result;

        try {
            result = type.findAlltTypes();
            assertNotNull(result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail("Exception caught with " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Its context is defined in `TestStackOverflowExample-context.xml`:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:testContext.properties" />
<context:annotation-config />
<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.connection.driver.class}" />
    <property name="url" value="${db.connection.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${db.connection.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db.connection.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="beanDAO" class="com.example.BeanDAOImpl">
    <property name="ds" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="beanDAOTwo" ref="beanDAOTwo"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="beanDAOTwo" class="com.example.BeanDAOTwoImpl">
    <property name="ds" ref="dataSource"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="type" class="com.example.TypeImpl">
    <property name="beanDAO" ref="beanDAO"></property>
</bean>
```

`TestContext.properties` is in classpath and contains only db-specific data needed for datasource.

This works like a charm but my question is - why doesn't it work when I try to manually wire beans and perform setter injection as in:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class TypeTest {

    private IType type;

    public IType getType () {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(IType type) {
        this.type= type;
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindAllTypes(){
    //snip, snip...
    }
}
```

What am I missing here? What part of configuration is wrong here? When I try to manually inject beans via setters, test fails because this part

```
result = type.findAlltTypes();
```

is resolved as null in runtime. I've, of course, consulted the Spring reference manual and tried various combinations of XML configuration; all I could conclude is that Spring was unable to inject beans because it somehow fails to properly dereference Spring Test Context reference but by using @Autowired this happens "automagically" and I really can't see why is that because JavaDoc of both `Autowired` annotation and its `PostProcessor` class doesn't mention this.

Also worth adding is the fact that `@Autowired` is used in application only here. Elsewhere only manual wiring is performed, so this also brings forth question - why is it working *there* and not **here**, in my test? What part of DI configuration am I missing? How does `@Autowired` get reference of Spring Context?

EDIT:
I've also tried this but with same results:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class TypeTest implements ApplicationContextAware{

    private IType type;

    private ApplicationContext ctx;

    public TypeTest(){
              super();
              ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("/TypeTest-context.xml");
              ctx.getBean("type");
    }

    public IType getType () {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(IType type) {
        this.type= type;
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindAllTypes(){
    //snip, snip...
    }
}
```

Any other ideas, perhaps?

EDIT2:
I've found a way without resorting to writing own `TestContextListener` or `BeanPostProcessor`. It is suprisingly simple and it turns out that I was on the right track with my last edit:

1) Constructor-based context resolving:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class TypeTest{

    private IType type;

    private ApplicationContext ctx;

    public TypeTest(){
         super();
         ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("/TypeTest-context.xml");
         type = ctx.getBean("type");
    }

    public IType getType () {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(IType type) {
        this.type= type;
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindAllTypes(){
    //snip, snip...
    }
}
```

2) By implementing ApplicationContextAware interface:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class TypeTest implements ApplicationContextAware{

    private IType type;
    private ApplicationContext ctx;

    public IType getType () {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(IType type) {
        this.type= type;
    }

@Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) throws BeansException {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    type = (Type) ctx.getBean("type");
}

    @Test
    public void testFindAllTypes(){
    //snip, snip...
    }
}
```

Both of these approaches properly instanced beans.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a look at the source of `org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener`, you will see the following method (formatted and commented for clarity):

```
protected void injectDependencies(final TestContext testContext)
throws Exception {
    Object bean = testContext.getTestInstance();
    AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory = testContext.getApplicationContext()
            .getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    beanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(bean, 

            AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_NO,
            // no autowiring!!!!!!!!

            false
        );

    beanFactory.initializeBean(bean, testContext.getTestClass().getName());
    // but here, bean post processors are run

    testContext.removeAttribute(REINJECT_DEPENDENCIES_ATTRIBUTE);
}
```

So the test object is a bean without auto-wiring. However, `@AutoWired`, `@Resource` etc, don't use the autowiring mechanism, they use `BeanPostProcessor`. And so the dependencies are injected if and only if the annotations are used (or if you register some other `BeanPostProcessor` that does it).

(The above code is from Spring 3.0.x, but I bet it was the same in 2.5.x)

Comment: So are we safe to conclude there is effectively no way to manually wire test beans? I would like to omit using annotations if at all possible.

Comment: Of course it can be done. In Spring, almost anything can be done. You would have to write your own a) BeanPostProcessor or b) TestExecutionListener, search for the bean for your test class and wire it up using the AutowireCapableBeanFactory.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Do you have perhaps an example or simple pointers on how would that be done?

Comment: No, I have never even thought about it until a minute ago. But Spring is pretty well-documented. Reading the javadocs for TestExecutionListener and AutowireCapableBeanFactory is probably a good start

Comment: When using JUnit3 and spring the autowire is not necessary so this functionality is available. Although with this setup you still need the setter. I'd rather be forced to add the @Autowire annotation than the setter method.

Comment: OK, but why would anybody still use JUnit 3?

Comment: I believe I have found a simpler solution - I've given an EDIT2 in my post. If there was any doubt, it goes to show how much more elegant using annotations is.

Comment: @Quantum I don't really like those solutions. The first version duplicates what @ContextConfiguration does and both require manual wiring. But still: you should put the code in your own answer. you can even \*shudder\* accept that answer then.

Comment: @Quantum You can still use annotations and selectively wire various beans manually.  You just need to make your test class BeanFactoryAware and set a BeanFactory field.  Spring will then automatically inject the applicationContext's bean factory into your test, and you can manually pull beans from it as you please.