# springjunit4classrunner test case throwing null pointer

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit4

I am using JUNIT4 + Spring and wrote a test case. I wired in a JDBC Template and did manual set on it. But that turns out be null and the test is throwing null pointer exception when i use that injected variable. What's wrong here?

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:applicationContextTest.xml" })
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
@Configurable
public class WriterTest {


    private JdbcTemplate utilityJdbcTemplate;

    public void setUtilityJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate utilityJdbcTemplate) {
        this.utilityJdbcTemplate = utilityJdbcTemplate;
    }



    @Test
    @Transactional
    @Rollback(true)
    public void testHappyPath() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(utilityJdbcTemplate);

    }
}
```

Here the test fails because utilityJdbcTemplate being null. why?

Comment: Not sure how to diagnose the issue w/o seeing the relevant config or code; with the code shown there's no reason for it *not* to be null.

Comment: I found the answer here by myself. Thanks for trying to help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133608/spring-junit4-manual-auto-wiring-dilemma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"gotta autowire":

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate utilityJdbcTemplate;
```

Comment: No. Autowire doesnt work. Its not that direct. I tried it. Answer is here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133608/spring-junit4-manual-auto-wiring-dilemma . I just dont want to delete this question as it would help somebody else

Comment: should work. `@Configurable` is not needed for your test. `@Autowired` and `@Resource` do work with `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` and `@ContextConfiguration`. Worked many.. many times.